# How to switch with another application when redeploying a WAR?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4

Sorry if this question was asked before, if it was, I didn't find it.

I'm using GlassFish 4.

When I need to redeploy an application (for fixing a bug for exemple), its URL will return temporarily a 404 NOT FOUND error until the application is fully redeployed.

My question is: do you know a way to redirect the URL to another application or a web page ("Application not available for the moment...") during the time the URL is inaccessible?

I heard of load balancer but it's between 2 servers (which I don't have).

Thank you.

Comment: Not very sure, but I think this should not happen. Did you double check the URL you're calling? Regarding the 404 you could just configure a custom 404 error page containing some "maintenance" related content.

Comment: @Gunnar thank you for your answer. I think I'll do that. It's easy to do and it'll do the job for now:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use rolling updates to update an application without any downtime, by using the :version suffix. For full information on how to do it, see the blog post at http://blog.payara.fish/payara-server-rolling-upgrades.